# How do I force apt-get to install a package that will not install due to a bug introduced by Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

Ubuntu 11.10 separated out python-profiler from the Python standard library due to licensing philosophies. (According to what I could Google, correct me if I'm wrong.)

This is an active bug since October for 11.10. I have Python 2.7.2 installed, so the dependency errors are wrong. 'apt-get check' does not resolve the problem.

What is the best way to resolve to this? Thank you.

```
sudo apt-get install python-profiler   

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-profiler : Depends: python (>= 2.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Note: Made a fresh install on a new system and python-profile appears to be present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `python-profile` package just includes a few `.py` files:

```
$ apt-file list python-profiler
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.5/profile.py
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.5/pstats.py
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.6/profile.py
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.6/pstats.py
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.7/profile.py
python-profiler: /usr/lib/python2.7/pstats.py
python-profiler: /usr/share/doc/python-profiler/README.Debian
python-profiler: /usr/share/doc/python-profiler/changelog.Debian.gz
python-profiler: /usr/share/doc/python-profiler/copyright
python-profiler: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/python-profiler
```

Hence, you can download the binary package using `apt-get download python-profiler` and extract its contents with `dpkg -x python-profiler_<version>_all.deb <dir>`. Once you have the contents of the package, you can just copy the `.py` files to their location to make the profiler modules available in your python installation.

Comment: +1 Definitely a better idea than potentially breaking apt just for the sake of a few .py sources :)

Comment: One more thing, since you're probably going to copy the `.py` files to a directory with root permissions, then it's a good idea to byte compile those files using `python -m compileall <dir>`.

Comment: Caesium, I was looking for a solution that was neutral (ie not breaking anything, or creating a new problem when the bug is fixed), but this looks like the best way to me too. Thanks